# Maven multi-project in bitbucket-pipelines possible?

Tags: maven, bitbucket-pipelines

Is it possible to build multi-projects in bitbucket pipelines?

When doing a mvn clean install of the parent repository via the pipeline it does not find the child projects.

Answer (score 0):

You can configure your bitbucket-pipelines.yml so :

```
 script: 
      - mvn -f parent-pom/pom.xml -B verify
```

parent-pom being your parent project.

Answer (score -1):

Try something like:

pipelines:
  default:
    - step:
        script: # Modify the commands below to build your repository.
          **- cd sub-project
          - mvn clean install package**